# Bash script to check ATM interface speed on list of routers and interfaces from file

Tags: linux, bash

I am new to bash scripting. Due to ACL limitations on the target devices I am tied to using bash on a host which I have user level access to rather than PHP on a device on another LAN segment.

I have a file of IP addresses and interfaces:

```
10.10.1.1 ATM0
10.10.2.1 ATM0/0/1
10.10.3.1 FastEthernet4
```

Etc. I need to connect to the IP, issue a command relative to the interface (e.g., `sh dsl int atm 0/0/1 | inc Speed`), record the results to a file, then logout and move on to the next host.

Thus far googling has brought me to the conclusion that bash cannot read the contents into a 2 dimensional array, and I am well and truly stuck.

Can anyone offer any guidance please? I am happy to cobble together the loop etc once I have the `$ip` and `$interface` set from the file.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
for line in $(sed 's/ \+/:/' ipfile.txt); do
    ip=$(echo $line | cut -f1 -d:)
    interface=$(echo $line | cut -f2- -d:)
    whatever_command $ip $interface
done
```